# Ruby - comparing integers derived from string

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and reading a number from a text file with

```
or_rating = line.scan((/\d+/)).map(&:to_i)
```

I then read another number with

```
offrating = line.scan((/\d+/)).map(&:to_i)
```

and then try to do a comparison

```
if offrating - 1 <= or_rating then...
```

but I get this error

```
can't convert Fixnum into Array (TypeError)
```

Most of the answers I have found refer to mapping `to_i` which I have tried (above) but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Why do you have double parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

Your `offrating` is an array and `or_rating` is yet another array.

And you are trying to do

```
Array - FixNum <= Array
```

So you get the error, as it tries to convert 1(FixNum) as well to `Array` to do `-` and comparison

If You expect `offrating` and `or_rating` to return a single element array always, then you can do,

```
offrating[0] - 1 <= or_rating[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`scan` returns an array.  The problem you are running in to is the `offrating - 1` part.

it's trying to subtract the number 1 from an `Array`.  If you add in the indexers, like so

```
if offrating[0] - 1 <= or_rating[0]
```

It may get rid of the error, but I don't know if that's going to give you the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

What tcshao and JSWorld said - you're getting an array out of your expression - an array of the numbers in the string. Looks like you want:

```
line.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).each_slice(2).select{ |or_rating, offrating| 
  offrating - 1 <= or_rating
}.each{ |or_rating, offrating|
  puts "Your Code Here"
}
```

Or you could use an `if` in the block instead of the `select`.